# run exec command as admin in MsBuild

Tags: angularjs, npm, msbuild, exec, npm-cli

I need to run the command `npm cache clean --force` as admin in my daily builds.

I am currently using the command:

`<Exec Command="npm cache clean --force" workingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)\Angular" />`

and it fails with the following error:

> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with MSBuild, nor the Exec task. What you have to do is login as a user with admin credentials to get this to work.

But first of all, ask why or what is requiring admin credentials in the first place?